# Javascript onclick Button Display Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I have created a form using Javascript and HTML and what I would like to achieve is when the user clicks "Add Item" button after filling out the default form fields a second row beneath the first form fields gets displayed with the same exact form fields displayed in the first one. Essentially allowing the user to add X amount of items to a "package" by utilizing the same form fields used in the first one. Trying to explain as best as possible. Currently the Code I am providing is displaying a DIV with sample text to get my head wrapped around what I want to happen. I am new to Javascript but willing to get my hands dirty. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Pick a Collection:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option class="array" value="">Lets get started..</option>
    <option class="array" value="Adirondack">Adirondack</option>
    <option class="array" value="Ridgeline">Ridgeline</option>
    <option class="array" value="Horizon">Horizon</option>
</select>
Choose an Item:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
Color:
<select id="slct3" name="slct3">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">1 Solid Color</option>
    <option value="">Mix and Match</option>
</select>
Quantity:
<select id="slct4" name="slct4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
    <option value="">5</option>
    <option value="">6</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<button id="addItem" onclick="document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML='you touched the button'">Add Item</button>


function populate(s1,s2) {
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "Adirondack") {
        var optionArray = ["|","shoreline|Shoreline Adirondack Chair - AD-0100","fanback|Fanback Adirondack Chair - AD-0101","coastal|Coastal Adirondack Chair - AD-0102", "leftWindsail|Left Windsail Adirondack Chair - AD-0103", "rightwindsail|Right Windsail Adirondack Chair - AD-0104", "roayale|Royale Adionrdack Chair - AD-0105", "folding|Folding Adirondack Chair - AD-0106", "kidz|Kidz Adirondack Chair - AD-0107","shoreline|Shoreline Adirondack Rocker - AD-0110", "fanbackrocker|Fanback Adirondack Rocker - AD-0111", "coastal|Coastal Adirondack Rocker - AD-0112" ];
    } else if(s1.value == "Ridgeline") {
        var optionArray = ["|","rl-0200|Ridgeline High Back Rocker - RL-0200","rl-0201-36|Ridgeline 36 Inch Gliding Bench - RL-0201-36","rl-0201-48|Ridgeline 48 Inch Gliding Bench - RL0201-48","rl-0201-60|Ridgeline 60 Inch Gliding Bench - RL0201-60" ];            
    } else if(s1.value == "Horizon") {
        var optionArray = ["|","hz-0300|Horizon High Back Rocker - HZ-0300","hz-0301-36|Horizon 36 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-36","rl-0201-48|Horizon 48 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-48","hz-0301-60|Horizon 60 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-60" ];          
    }               
for(var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML=  pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);      
}   
}
```

Comment: You could look into using jquery and the .clone() method, http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: I will look into this method would like to keep it all javascript for now but I will indeed look into it

Answer (score 0):

You may put your form fields within a `div` and have an empty `div` next to it. On the click of the `button`, the `innerHTML` of the first `div` will be copied and **appended** (hence the `+=` operator) to the `innerHTML` of the second `div`. This should solve your problem. And, by the way, it’s undesirable to have the same value for more than one `option` of a `select` (I haven’t fixed it though).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_item(){
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
}
function populate(slct){
var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var len = sels.length;
var val = slct.options[slct.selectedIndex].value;
var optionArray, pair, newOption;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(slct == sels[i]){
        sels[i+1].options.length = 0;
            if(val == "Adirondack"){
            optionArray = [ "|","shoreline|Shoreline Adirondack Chair - AD-0100","fanback|Fanback Adirondack Chair - AD-0101","coastal|Coastal Adirondack Chair - AD-0102", "leftWindsail|Left Windsail Adirondack Chair - AD-0103", "rightwindsail|Right Windsail Adirondack Chair - AD-0104", "roayale|Royale Adionrdack Chair - AD-0105", "folding|Folding Adirondack Chair - AD-0106", "kidz|Kidz Adirondack Chair - AD-0107","shoreline|Shoreline Adirondack Rocker - AD-0110", "fanbackrocker|Fanback Adirondack Rocker - AD-0111", "coastal|Coastal Adirondack Rocker - AD-0112" ];
            }
            else if(val == "Ridgeline"){
            optionArray = [ "|","rl-0200|Ridgeline High Back Rocker - RL-0200","rl-0201-36|Ridgeline 36 Inch Gliding Bench - RL-0201-36","rl-0201-48|Ridgeline 48 Inch Gliding Bench - RL0201-48","rl-0201-60|Ridgeline 60 Inch Gliding Bench - RL0201-60" ];
            }
            else if(val == "Horizon"){
            optionArray = [ "|","hz-0300|Horizon High Back Rocker - HZ-0300","hz-0301-36|Horizon 36 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-36","rl-0201-48|Horizon 48 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-48","hz-0301-60|Horizon 60 Inch Gliding Bench - HZ-0301-60" ];
            }
            for(var option in optionArray) {
            pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML=  pair[1];
            sels[i+1].options.add(newOption);      
            }   
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="add_item();">
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
Pick a Collection:
<select name="slct1[]" onchange="populate(this);">
    <option class="array" value="">Lets get started..</option>
    <option class="array" value="Adirondack">Adirondack</option>
    <option class="array" value="Ridgeline">Ridgeline</option>
    <option class="array" value="Horizon">Horizon</option>
</select>
Choose an Item:
<select name="slct2[]">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
Color:
<select name="slct3[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">1 Solid Color</option>
    <option value="">Mix and Match</option>
</select>
Quantity:
<select name="slct4[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
    <option value="">5</option>
    <option value="">6</option>
</select>
<br/>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="add_item();">Add Item</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey this worked for me thanks, but now my dynamic drop-downs are acting rather strange. I have re-edited my original post and provided Javascript for populate Function on first select item. You should give my form a try and then add item to see how its being affected. I tried to dump it into JSfiddle but It was not rendering my javascript properly I think it was my array. Any suggestions will certainly be appreciated or any links/topics thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Dutta sorry bout late response I was able to add row but my items were not saving their values for each drop-down. Damn it i have to go in on some tutorials. You seem to have a good grip do you recommend any tutorial materials?